# How to style a code block to make all the colours look pretty like my IDE and here in stackoverflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogs, blogger

When putting code samples in my [blog](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk) I would like the code to have all the appropriate colours. How can I do that?

Basically if I write:

```
foreach (ListItem item in items)
{
    item.Text = "something";
}
```

I want it to appear in the correct colours like it does in my Visual Studio or here at stack**overflow**.

I'm bored of styling the colours of each key word manually. Is there a pre-existing javascript library I can use?

EDIT:
I'm using blogger as my blogging platform if that helps

Comment: http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I'd like to have jballs comment as the answer... but I can't. He was right though - [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter) seems to be the easiest to get/use and there is a lot of support for it too.

I implemented it really quickly. Tested it and explained my steps here: [Colouring code with Syntax Highlighter](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/04/colouring-code-with-syntax-highlighter.html)

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to use a JavaScript library to style up the code samples. You can use [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) to do syntax highlighting on a webapage, the [README](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) explains exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a place that hosts the code (like http://gist.github.com , http://snipplr.com/ , and various other 'pastebin' services) and then just use the embed script that they provide.

Answer (score 1):

Google "syntax highlighter".  There are a bunch of libraries out there, many use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [syntax highlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/). If you are using a particular CMS, there are probably modules already created for this.

Comment: Thanks! Although this link is out of date

Answer (score 1):

I used [Windows Live Writer](http://windowslivewriter.spaces.live.com/) for a while, and there is a plugin to [paste from Visual Studio](http://www.11011.net/software/vspaste), that does the colour coding for you. I then coded that content into my Blogger/Wordpress post.

Now I use a java based plug-in for Wordpress [SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/), which provides line wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:**

link tutorial

> - [Adding **Syntax Highlighting** to **Blogger**](http://heisencoder.net/2009/01/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-blogger.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vim's export as html, and then copy&paste in blogger. No the best solution, but probably the simplest.